# VBA code that sums up VlOOKUP and COUNTIF

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, countif

I'm trying to compare each cell of a column (column1) with all cells in another column (column2) and get the result as how many times we have matches.

In excel Using VLOOKUP, I created column3 which gives results as "match" and "no match" and then using COUNTIF the "match" cells. Is there any way to avoid this column3 and directly get the result the total number of matches?

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: try https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-filter-function with counta() around it.. and share how far it works/doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below function.

```
 =SUM(--(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1:A4,B1:B4,0))))
```

The formula may need to array entry for non 365 versions of excel. Array entry means confirm formula entry by pressing `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use that vba code. Feel free to change it as you like.

```
Sub GetMatces()
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, result As Integer, cell1 As Range, 
cell2 As Range

result = 0
Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A8")  'Here you can put the exact range to run the code or you can set it as a selection with "set rng=application.selection"
Set rng2 = ActiveSheet.Range("b1:b8")

For Each cell1 In rng1
For Each cell2 In rng2
    If cell1 = cell2 Then result = result + 1
Next cell2
Next cell1

MsgBox result 'that variable is the sum of the matces. you can do it everything you want
End Sub
```